# finish() not working while using android monkey tool

Tags: android, android-activity, android-monkey

I have an activity that overrides `onBackPressed()`, and within this function, I explicitly call `finish()`, since I need to do some clean up before the app exits.

When I do run the app normally, and click on the `BACK` key, the app exits normally.

When I run the monkey tool with the following command,

```
adb shell monkey -v --pct-syskeys 100 -p com.my.app 100
```

according to the logs, the `onBackPressed()` function is called, but the `finish()` does not close the activity/app. I've been trying to figure out what the problem is for sometime, but could not so far. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
As per the comment, I'm posting the `onBackPressed()` code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if (bIsBackKeyPressed)
    return;

    // do some clean up

    bIsBackKeyPressed = true;
    finish();
}
```

The reason I'm using the `bIsBackKeyPressed` flag, is because the monkey tool sends the `BACK` key multiple times.

It is possible that this happens in conjunction with other key presses, along with the `BACK` key, but I'm not sure about that.

Thanks,
Rajath

Comment: can u post your `onBackPressed()` method's body.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07, I've posted the code

Comment: @rajath : you missed to call  `super.onBackPressed();`.  check it once and let me know

Comment: @Praveen, this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find out what the problem was. There is some additional information that I should have mentioned in my question. This was the logs for the monkey tool:

```
// Allowing start of Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.my.app/.main.MainActivity } in package com.my.app
// Rejecting start of Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.htc.launcher/.Launcher } in package com.htc.launcher
```

From the monkey docs, if I used the following command for running monkey

```
adb shell monkey -v --pct-syskeys 100 -p com.my.app -p com.htc.launcher 100
```

then it is ok. Notice that I have added the following: `-p com.htc.launcher`

So, what happens is that by not giving the additional parameters, when the `BACK` is sent to the app, the clean up takes place in `onBackPressed()`, but `finish()` is not called as the `com.htc.launcher` app is not given permission to run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
        if (!bIsBackKeyPressed)
        {
            bIsBackKeyPressed = true;
            finish();
        }
        return true;
    } 
    else 
    {
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: @rajath - I don't know but in if condition it should be if(!bIsBackKeyPressed) or Inside if loop it should be bIsBackKeyPressed=false..use of this flag is to prevent firing back key multiple times..am i right?

Comment: that's the code in your solution that needs correction - I took care of that when I tried it out